# Wheelnav.js, navItem Title clockwise function

Tags: javascript, navigation, wheelnav.js

Is it possible to clockwise title only in selected navItems? What I have found works on all of them:

```
wheel.titleCurved = true;
wheel.titleCurvedClockwise = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify only the selected navItem because it changes dynamically.

However, you can modify navItems individually after initialization.

```
var wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
wheel.clickModeRotate = false;
wheel.titleCurved = true;
wheel.initWheel(["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]);
wheel.navItems[3].titleCurvedClockwise = true;
wheel.createWheel();
```